# How to handle PHP function error?

Tags: php, exception, conditional-statements

How do I form an `if/else` statement for a PHP function failing? I want it to define `$results` one way if it works and another if it doesn't. I don't want to simply show an error or kill the error message if it fails.

Currently, I have:

```
if(file_get_contents("http://www.address.com")){
    $results = "it worked";}
else {
    $results = "it didnt";}
return $results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(@file_get_contents("http://www.address.com");){
    $results = "it worked";}
else {
    $results = "it didnt";}
return $results
```

By prepending an @ to a function, you can surpress its error message.

Answer (score 2):

you want PHP's [try/catch functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

it goes something like:

```
try {
    // your functions
}
catch (Exception e){
    //fail gracefully
}
```

Comment: I think try/catch only works in PHP5 and with exceptions thrown using throw. Not sure though...

Comment: x3ro is right, I'm afraid try/catch only works with exceptions which are only thrown by PHP's new OO style functionality such as PDO. So not inbuilt functions like file_get_contents() which raises a warning error if the file doesn't exist.

You can throw an exception from anywhere, however, and I think it is possible to send normal fatal errors to an exception via the ErrorException class. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

Answer (score 0):

As contagious said, a try/catch function works well if the function throws an exception. But, I think what you are looking for is a good way to handle the result of a function returns your expected result, and not necessarily if it throws an exception. I don't think file_get_contents will throw an exception, but rather just return false.

Your code would work fine, but I noticed an extra ; in the first line of your if statement.

```
if (file_get_contents("http://www.address.com")) {
    $results = "it worked";
} else {
    $results = "it didnt";
}
return $results;
```

Also, you can store the result of a function call into a variable so you can use it later.

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://www.address.com");
if ($result) {
    // parse your results using $result
} else {
    // the url content could not be fetched, fail gracefully
}
```